Not getting code suggestions while using PY Charm for Pytest with POM
I am trying POM in PY Charm using PY Test but I am not able to get code suggestion's in the page.py file even though I am referring to driver from test.py file.
PY Charm Version :
PyCharm 2024.1.6 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-241.19072.16, built on August 8, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+1-b1207.30 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  Docker (241.19072.22)

File Name: HOME_PAGE.py
from selenium import webdriver


class HomePageCheck:
    def __init__(self, driver: webdriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def home_page_check(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

File Name: TEST_HOME_PAGE.py
from selenium import webdriver


class HomePageCheck:
    def __init__(self, driver: webdriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def home_page_check(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

Actual Output
Expected Output
I should get suggestion in HOME_PAGE.py file after using self.driver
